# Applying GroupBy and then apply Count in Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have the following in my Google cloud storage

```
Advertiser | Event
__________________
100 | Click

101 | Impression

100 | Impression

100 | Impression

101 | Impression
```

My output of the pipeline should be something like

```
Advertiser | Clicks | Impressions

100 | 1 | 2

101 | 0 | 2
```

First I used groupByKey, the output is like

> 100 Click, Impression, Impression
>
> 101 Impression, Impression

Now is it possible to count the value in KV?

Currently I just used comparing strings to count the clicks and impressions.

Is it possible to use count transforms over here?

Or do we any other transforms to be used here?

Or the way that I did is the only way?

Thanks,
Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your input is available as a `PCollection<KV<Long, EventType>> input` where the `Long` is the advertiser ID and `EventType` is an `enum { CLICK, IMPRESSION, possibly something else }`.

I'm also assuming you want the output to be a PCollection> where AdvertiserStats is a class with fields "numClicks", "numImpressions".

In that case one way to achieve what you want is to use [Combine](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/combine) - `input.apply(Combine.<Long, AdvertiserStats>perKey(new ComputeAdvertiserStatsFn()))`, where `ComputeAdvertiserStatsFn` is defined something like this:

```
public class ComputeAdvertiserStatsFn
    extends CombineFn<EventType, AdvertiserStats, AdvertiserStats> {
  public AdvertiserStats createAccumulator() { return new AdvertiserStats(); }
  public void addInput(AdvertiserStats stats, EventType input) {
    switch (input) {
    case CLICK: stats.numClicks++; break;
    case IMPRESSION: stats.numImpressions++; break;
    default: (depending on your application?)
    }
  }
  public AdvertiserStats mergeAccumulators(Iterable<AdvertiserStats> stats) {
    AdvertiserStats merged = createAccumulator();
    for (AdvertiserStats item : stats) {
      merged.numClicks += item.numClicks;
      merged.numImpressions += item.numImpressions;
    }
    return merged;
  }
  public AdvertiserStats extractOutput(AdvertiserStats stats) { return stats; }
}
```

This should perform very well because most of the grouping and counting will happen locally.

Currently, AFAIK, there is no `PTransform` that would do the work of `ComputeAdvertiserStatsFn` for you. I think the ideal interface would look something like `input.apply(Combine.perKey(Count.perElement()))`, but it wouldn't work with the way these are currently defined.

Comment: I will try this solution. But this is more or less same as what I did. I did it by writing a DoFn in which I will count every impressions and clicks. I thought that is not the efficient way. Does your solution would perform well with huge data?

Comment: I suppose you mean a solution where you GroupByKey by the advertiser ID and then count different event types in your DoFn. The suggested Combine-based solution should perform significantly better, because Combine applies most of the grouping and combining locally, thus greatly decreasing the amount of data shuffled and hence of overall IO. Basically, every time you can express your aggregation as a Combine, you should.